# Font awesome Icons doesn't appears

Tags: html, css, asp.net, fonts, font-awesome

I'm working on an ASp/net application and i use font-awesome for some icons.
My problem is that icons doesn't appears. I have the last verison of font awesome
here is my code in my nested master:

```
<li class="active"><asp:HyperLink ID="lnkAccueil" runat="server" NavigateUrl ="~/Views/Accueil.aspx" Title="Accueil"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> </asp:HyperLink></li>
```

I call my file in my master:

```
<link href="~/Content/Styles/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

and the path is correct.

And here you have the result:
[image]

this is the console
[image]

I do the same in another project and everything works. I really don't unterstand.
If someone has an answer..

Comment: inspect your web page , check your console, it will tell you the storey

Comment: @this.girish Thanks it looks like the download of the font fail I edit my question and post the log of the console

Comment: @Chirag thank for the tip

Comment: HIT "ctrl+f5" try to reload your page, you are running low net connection it seems or your css  path is incorrect

Comment: Did you place the font in the folder ? and linked them correctly?

Comment: @this.girish It's weird because on another project wit hthe same connection i did'nt have any problem

Comment: @SahilDhir yes everythings is ok from this point thanks

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: @Chirag Thanks a lot it works now.